# Why does my app force close on moving from one fragment to another on a ImageView click in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to move from `mycontacts extends Fragment` to `tasks extends Fragment` on clicking an `ImageView`. My ImageView is in a `ListView` which is generated using a `SimpleAdapter`.The ids of my layouts are as follows:`R.id.tasky` for the tasks fragment,`R.id.mycontacts` for the mycontacts fragment.  My codes and error logs are as follows. As I am new to fragments kindly explain to me step by step.

mycontacts extends Fragment

```
 purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     android.app.FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new tasks();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tasky, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
});
```

error logs:

```
04-22 04:41:52.486: E/FragmentManager(3250): No view found for id 0x7f04004f (com.example.taskmanager:id/tasky) for fragment tasks{b4ee0f70 #1 id=0x7f04004f}
04-22 04:41:52.486: E/FragmentManager(3250): Activity state:
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): Process: com.example.taskmanager, PID: 3250
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f04004f (com.example.taskmanager:id/tasky) for fragment tasks{b4ee0f70 #1 id=0x7f04004f}
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 04:41:53.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 04:45:17.276: E/FragmentManager(3351): No view found for id 0x7f04004f (com.example.taskmanager:id/tasky) for fragment tasks{b4ef7ac0 #1 id=0x7f04004f}
04-22 04:45:17.276: E/FragmentManager(3351): Activity state:
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): Process: com.example.taskmanager, PID: 3351
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f04004f (com.example.taskmanager:id/tasky) for fragment tasks{b4ef7ac0 #1 id=0x7f04004f}
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 04:45:18.476: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you do not have a container with id `R.id.tasky` i your mycontacts fragment layout

Comment: Is `tasky` your `FrameLayout` id?

Comment: No its my LinearLayout id

Answer (score 1):

Your mycontacts `Fragment` xml does not have a `ViewGroup` with the id `R.id.tasky`. You can use interface as a call back to the activity and then replace existing fragment in the container with another.

You can find code snippets @

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In the example in the docs there is `ListFragment` on `ListItemClick` communicate value to `Activity`. Then in activity replace existing fragment with a new one and communicate value to the same.

Similarly on `ImageView` click communicate to activity then from activity replace appropriate fragment in the container.